# Complex eigenvector/eigenvalues of real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I hope someone can help me with this exercise:

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n x n}$ a matrix with eigenvalue $a+ib$ and its
>   eigenvector $u+iv$. Show that $u,v$ are linearly independent from $u+iv$.

I'm thankful for every hint.

Comment: The MathJax used on this site should pose no problems if you are familiar with LaTeX - just use dollar signs and the formulae you'd normally type in TeX.

Comment: Would the case $n=2$ be of interest, or would that case be too trivial to consider?

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain if your claim is that both $\{u, u + vi\}$ and $\{v, u + vi\}$ are linearly independent sets or that $\{u, v, u + vi\}$ is a linearly independent set, but considering that the latter is impossible for $n = 2,$ I assume you wish to prove the former. Further, the claim is not true unless we assume that $b \neq 0.$ Consider the matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ We have that $\det(xI - A) = x^2 - 1$ so that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm 1$ with respective eigenvectors $v_1 = (1, 1)$ and $v_{-1} = (-1, 1),$ from which it follows that $v = (0, 0)$ in both cases.

We will assume that there exist constants $c$ and $d$ such that $cu + d(u + vi) = 0.$ Consequently, we have that $$0 = A \cdot 0 = A[cu + d(u + vi)] = cAu + dA(u + vi) = cAu + d(a + bi)(u + vi).$$ But this implies that $cAu = -d(a + bi)(u + vi)$ -- a contradiction. (Why?) We conclude that $u$ and $u + vi$ are linearly independent. One can use the analogous argument to show that $v$ and $u + vi$ are linearly indepenent.